# get child element from child element xml android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml i want to get any element not By order or get child element from another child element , i want to get ***Description*** tag from ***available products*** tag  and ***attributes*** of it i search a lot but i am beginner with android i can not got it .

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <AVSearch_PropertyDetails RequestedCurrency="sd">
  <Property IDHotel="10" PropertyCode="56" Hotelname="tggt" StarCategory="0" ImageIdentifier="ghj" NumberOfRooms="80" CheckinTime="00:00" CheckoutTime="23:59" Email="hjhj" Status="0">
   <GEOData CountryCode="hhj" CountryName="nnm" City="ghghgj" IDCity="565" Zip="656" Street="hyhjyjhy" Longitude="677" Latitude="6y7677">
    <Distances>
     <Distance Type="1" Distance="0.50" />
     <Distance Type="2" Distance="1.81" />
    </Distances>
   </GEOData>
   <Descriptions>
    <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="1" Text="This is the test hotel used for testing and debugging purposes only. Please do not book this hotel. This hotels is located in the center of the city where all public transportation means meet. It is also steps away from major monuments and land marks of the city such as status and very high building. The hotel overlooks the main river. It is furnished with very modern style furniture designed especially for guest comfort." />
    <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="4" Text="This is a testhotel" />
    <Description IDLanguage="4" IDType="3" Text="Terms &amp; conditions EN" />
   </Descriptions>
   <PropAmenities>
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="1" Text="24-hour front desk" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="42" Text="Free parking" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="65" Text="Outdoor parking" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="98" Text="Vending machines" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="101" Text="Wheel chair access" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="106" Text="Bell staff/porter" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="2" IDAmenity="128" Text="Room service - limited hours" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="3" IDAmenity="3" Text="City" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="3" IDAmenity="4" Text="Downtown" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="4" IDAmenity="20" Text="Hotel" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="4" IDAmenity="47" Text="Full service" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="4" IDAmenity="57" Text="Luxury" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="1" Text="Cash" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="3" Text="Voucher" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="5" Text="Credit card" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="7" Text="Check" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="22" Text="Frequent guest number" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="28" Text="Wire payment" />
    <PropAmenity IDType="6" IDAmenity="30" Text="Corporte ID/CD number" />
   </PropAmenities>
  </Property>
  <AvailableProducts>
   <Roomtype IDRoom="1" Code="A1D" NormBed="1" Maxbed="2" Category="3" Order="4">
    <Description Name="Deluxe Double Room" IDLanguage="4" />
    <RoomAmenities>
     <RoomAmenity IDType="101" IDAmenity="9" Text="Single" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="1" Text="Adjoining rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="2" Text="Air conditioning" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="5" Text="AM/FM radio" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="18" Text="Cable television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="20" Text="Color television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="22" Text="Connecting rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="26" Text="Cribs" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="28" Text="Desk" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="29" Text="Desk with lamp" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="53" Text="International direct dialing" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="70" Text="Modem" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="73" Text="Newspaper" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="78" Text="Pay per view movies on TV" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="92" Text="Safe" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="208" Text="Maid service" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="209" Text="PC hook-up in room" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="210" Text="Satellite television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="227" Text="Premium movie channels" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="235" Text="International channels" />
    </RoomAmenities>
    <Ratecode IDRatecode="9629" Ratecode="PR2" IDRatelevel="9205" Ratelevel="PR2" Markup="0.00" MarkupType="0" MealsRate="0.00" Commission="0.00" MealsInclusive="0" GuaranteeRequired="2" Rate="1998.00" TotalRate="1998.00" NetRate="1998.00" Availability="4">
     <Description RatecodeName="IBE None refundable rate" Text="Full stay non refundable deposit will be charged. No cancellation or modifies are allowed." IDLanguage="4" />
     <RatesByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="1" Children="0" Rate="1998.00" TotalRate="1998.00" NetRate="1998.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="1998.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="2" Children="0" Rate="1998.00" TotalRate="1998.00" NetRate="1998.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="1998.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
     </RatesByOccupancy>
    </Ratecode>
    <Ratecode IDRatecode="7038" Ratecode="IBE" IDRatelevel="6602" Ratelevel="IBE" Markup="0.00" MarkupType="0" MealsRate="0.00" Commission="0.00" MealsInclusive="0" GuaranteeRequired="2" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00" Availability="4">
     <Description RatecodeName="Best Available Rate" Text="Test hotel rate" IDLanguage="4" />
     <RatesByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="1" Children="0" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2198.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="2" Children="0" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2198.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
     </RatesByOccupancy>
    </Ratecode>
   </Roomtype>
   <Roomtype IDRoom="3956" Code="C1S" NormBed="1" Maxbed="1" Category="1" Order="1">
    <Description Name="Superior Single Room " IDLanguage="4" />
    <RoomAmenities>
     <RoomAmenity IDType="101" IDAmenity="9" Text="Single" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="1" Text="Adjoining rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="2" Text="Air conditioning" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="3" Text="Alarm clock" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="4" Text="All news channel" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="5" Text="AM/FM radio" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="7" Text="Balcony/Lanai/Terrace" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="13" Text="Bathtub" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="14" Text="Bathtub only" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="15" Text="Bathtub/shower combination" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="16" Text="Bidet" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="17" Text="Bottled water" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="18" Text="Cable television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="19" Text="Coffee/Tea maker" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="20" Text="Color television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="21" Text="Computer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="22" Text="Connecting rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="23" Text="Converters/ Voltage adaptors" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="26" Text="Cribs" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="27" Text="Data port" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="28" Text="Desk" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="29" Text="Desk with lamp" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="31" Text="Direct dial phone number" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="38" Text="Fax machine" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="39" Text="Fire alarm" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="40" Text="Fire alarm with light" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="41" Text="Fireplace" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="46" Text="Free movies/video" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="47" Text="Full kitchen" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="50" Text="Hairdryer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="51" Text="High speed internet connection" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="53" Text="International direct dialing" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="54" Text="Internet access" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="55" Text="Iron" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="57" Text="Jacuzzi" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="61" Text="Kitchenette" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="69" Text="Minibar" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="70" Text="Modem" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="71" Text="Modem jack" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="73" Text="Newspaper" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="74" Text="Non-smoking" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="78" Text="Pay per view movies on TV" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="84" Text="Printer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="85" Text="Private bathroom" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="87" Text="Recliner" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="88" Text="Refrigerator" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="90" Text="Remote control television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="91" Text="Rollaway bed" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="92" Text="Safe" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="94" Text="Separate closet" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="97" Text="Shower only" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="99" Text="Sitting area" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="100" Text="Smoke detectors" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="101" Text="Smoking" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="103" Text="Speaker phone" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="104" Text="Stereo" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="107" Text="Telephone" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="135" Text="Foam pillows" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="208" Text="Maid service" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="210" Text="Satellite television" />
    </RoomAmenities>
    <Ratecode IDRatecode="7038" Ratecode="IBE" IDRatelevel="6602" Ratelevel="IBE" Markup="0.00" MarkupType="0" MealsRate="0.00" Commission="0.00" MealsInclusive="0" GuaranteeRequired="2" Rate="2220.00" TotalRate="2220.00" NetRate="2220.00" Availability="1">
     <Description RatecodeName="Best Available Rate" Text="Test hotel rate" IDLanguage="4" />
     <RatesByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="1" Children="0" Rate="2220.00" TotalRate="2220.00" NetRate="2220.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2220.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
     </RatesByOccupancy>
    </Ratecode>
   </Roomtype>
   <Roomtype IDRoom="3" Code="C1T" NormBed="1" Maxbed="1" Category="1" Order="2">
    <Description Name="Standard Single Room with Sea View" Text="Standard Single room Looking over the ocean from the balcony side and from the window side is looking over the market place of teh city center right next to the church" IDLanguage="4" />
    <RoomAmenities>
     <RoomAmenity IDType="101" IDAmenity="9" Text="Single" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="1" Text="Adjoining rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="2" Text="Air conditioning" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="3" Text="Alarm clock" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="4" Text="All news channel" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="5" Text="AM/FM radio" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="7" Text="Balcony/Lanai/Terrace" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="13" Text="Bathtub" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="14" Text="Bathtub only" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="15" Text="Bathtub/shower combination" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="16" Text="Bidet" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="17" Text="Bottled water" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="18" Text="Cable television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="19" Text="Coffee/Tea maker" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="20" Text="Color television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="21" Text="Computer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="22" Text="Connecting rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="23" Text="Converters/ Voltage adaptors" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="26" Text="Cribs" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="27" Text="Data port" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="28" Text="Desk" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="29" Text="Desk with lamp" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="31" Text="Direct dial phone number" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="38" Text="Fax machine" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="39" Text="Fire alarm" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="40" Text="Fire alarm with light" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="41" Text="Fireplace" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="46" Text="Free movies/video" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="47" Text="Full kitchen" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="50" Text="Hairdryer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="51" Text="High speed internet connection" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="53" Text="International direct dialing" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="54" Text="Internet access" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="55" Text="Iron" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="57" Text="Jacuzzi" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="61" Text="Kitchenette" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="69" Text="Minibar" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="70" Text="Modem" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="71" Text="Modem jack" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="73" Text="Newspaper" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="74" Text="Non-smoking" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="78" Text="Pay per view movies on TV" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="84" Text="Printer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="85" Text="Private bathroom" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="87" Text="Recliner" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="88" Text="Refrigerator" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="90" Text="Remote control television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="91" Text="Rollaway bed" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="92" Text="Safe" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="94" Text="Separate closet" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="97" Text="Shower only" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="99" Text="Sitting area" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="100" Text="Smoke detectors" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="101" Text="Smoking" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="103" Text="Speaker phone" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="104" Text="Stereo" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="107" Text="Telephone" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="135" Text="Foam pillows" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="208" Text="Maid service" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="210" Text="Satellite television" />
    </RoomAmenities>
    <Ratecode IDRatecode="7038" Ratecode="IBE" IDRatelevel="6602" Ratelevel="IBE" Markup="0.00" MarkupType="0" MealsRate="0.00" Commission="0.00" MealsInclusive="0" GuaranteeRequired="2" Rate="2220.00" TotalRate="2220.00" NetRate="2220.00" Availability="2">
     <Description RatecodeName="Best Available Rate" Text="Test hotel rate" IDLanguage="4" />
     <RatesByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="1" Children="0" Rate="2220.00" TotalRate="2220.00" NetRate="2220.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2220.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
     </RatesByOccupancy>
    </Ratecode>
   </Roomtype>
   <Roomtype IDRoom="52" Code="B2D" NormBed="2" Maxbed="3" Category="3" Order="9">
    <Description Name="Superior Quadtruple Room" IDLanguage="4" />
    <RoomAmenities>
     <RoomAmenity IDType="101" IDAmenity="1" Text="Double" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="1" Text="Adjoining rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="2" Text="Air conditioning" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="3" Text="Alarm clock" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="4" Text="All news channel" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="5" Text="AM/FM radio" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="7" Text="Balcony/Lanai/Terrace" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="13" Text="Bathtub" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="14" Text="Bathtub only" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="15" Text="Bathtub/shower combination" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="16" Text="Bidet" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="17" Text="Bottled water" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="18" Text="Cable television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="19" Text="Coffee/Tea maker" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="20" Text="Color television" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="21" Text="Computer" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="22" Text="Connecting rooms" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="23" Text="Converters/ Voltage adaptors" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="26" Text="Cribs" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="27" Text="Data port" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="28" Text="Desk" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="29" Text="Desk with lamp" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="31" Text="Direct dial phone number" />
     <RoomAmenity IDType="102" IDAmenity="53" Text="International direct dialing" />
    </RoomAmenities>
    <Ratecode IDRatecode="7038" Ratecode="IBE" IDRatelevel="6602" Ratelevel="IBE" Markup="0.00" MarkupType="0" MealsRate="0.00" Commission="0.00" MealsInclusive="0" GuaranteeRequired="2" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00" Availability="5">
     <Description RatecodeName="Best Available Rate" Text="Test hotel rate" IDLanguage="4" />
     <RatesByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="1" Children="0" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2198.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="2" Children="0" Rate="2198.00" TotalRate="2198.00" NetRate="2198.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2198.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
      <RateByOccupancy Adults="3" Children="0" Rate="2208.00" TotalRate="2208.00" NetRate="2208.00">
       <DailyRates>
        <DailyRate Day="12.04.2016" Rate="2208.00" />
       </DailyRates>
      </RateByOccupancy>
     </RatesByOccupancy>
    </Ratecode>
   </Roomtype>
  </AvailableProducts>
 </AVSearch_PropertyDetails>
```

**Here is my code**

```
   XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xmlresult); // getting DOM element

    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/AVSearch_PropertyDetails/AvailableProducts/Roomtype/Description/[@Name='']");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: Have tried using XPath?

Comment: no not yet i tried more example but not like my xml format please if you can help me .

Comment: how can i using XPath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Comment: @Fildor i updated my code you can look ? with xpath